# php mysql join query alias

Tags: php, mysql

Two tables. I want to select 2 names from settings table. I think a join table would be overboard for this simple requirement, let me know.

Error Number: 1066

Not unique table/alias: 'settings'

```
SELECT `parameter`.*, `settings`.`name` as `unitname`, `settings`.`name` as `sourcename` 
FROM `parameter` 
INNER JOIN `settings` ON `parameter`.`unit_id` = `settings`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `settings` ON `parameter`.`source_id` = `settings`.`id` 
WHERE `parameter`.`isdeleted` =0 
ORDER BY `parameter`.`id` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You're joining the same table twice, so when you refer to that table the query engine has no way to know which joined table you mean.  Alias your tables (give them temporary names within the query) to keep them separately identifiable:

```
SELECT
  `parameter`.*,
  `unit_settings`.`name` as `unitname`,
  `source_settings`.`name` as `sourcename`
FROM
  `parameter`
  INNER JOIN `settings` AS `unit_settings` ON `parameter`.`unit_id` = `unit_settings`.`id`
  INNER JOIN `settings` AS `source_settings` ON `parameter`.`source_id` = `source_settings`.`id`
WHERE
  `parameter`.`isdeleted` = 0
ORDER BY
  `parameter`.`id` DESC
```